# Use of auxiliary verbs in a comparison structure

Tags: comparisons, auxiliary-verbs

Think about the following sentence.

> A culture in which the citizens share similar religious beliefs and values is more likely to have laws that represent the wishes of its people than **is** a culture where citizens come from diverse backgrounds.

I have 2 questions regarding this sentence.

1) Is that highlighted **is** a main verb of the second part of the sentence or is it just an auxiliary verb?

2) Is it grammatically correct to omit this **is**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answers:**

1. The verb **is** which you highlighted and asked about is called a copula.
2. Yes, it can be omitted and the sentence will still be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Allow me to ask 1 additional question. Suppose the sentence goes like "A looks taller than B", is there a need to include such a copula for the B part? It doesn't sound right to say "A looks taller than looks B".

Comment: @LTW Oh no you wouldn't say that for sure (the second one). The first is correct. That's not exactly a copula btw. **"Is"** is a special type of verb called a copula or copulative verb. It's a form of "be" or "being" and they are used to link ideas. If you did want to use the second form you would rearrange such as: "A looks taller than *B looks*". It's too verbose anyway. The first form is preferable.